# UiAlertView should change ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

What is wrong with following code? I will change the viewController, when the text in the alertView is not empty. The problem is, it will change the `UiViewController` every time, even it is empty.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        if ([[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text isEqual:@""]) {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error warning" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];
        }
        else{

            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChangeView"];
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you checking that the text is actually empty?

Comment: With your code,in first alert, if you let it empty (dont input), app will show alert  "Error warning", and when you you press button OK, it will turn to case "else" to change the UIViewController.
I think in alert "Error warning", the delegate should be nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this check instead:

```
if (![[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text.length) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error warning" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
} else ...
```

Comment: He is doing this already? Just different syntax.. but the same check. isEqual:@"" is the same as length 0. Not so?

Comment: Another short question. Even the textfield is empty, it should open an "error AlertView". It works, but the "error AlertView" will pop up a hounder times. Why?

Comment: @tander It depends. If the text on a textField isn't set, I believe it gives you `nil` instead of an empty string. Checking `!textField.text.length` will pass if the length is zero OR if the string is `nil`.

Comment: @Nanog000 I think it's because you're using the same `UIAlertViewDelegate` method to handle both `alertView`s. Try just setting the delegate for your error `alertView` to `nil` since you don't need to take any action when OK is pressed on that one.